# How can I show a Div on page 1 while page 2 is loading and display page 2 after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three pages on my site.

Page 1:  A simple page where the user enters the database search criteria

Page 2:  An HTML5 Adobe Edge animated page

Page 3:  The search results page

Page 1 loads very fast.  Pages 2 and 3 load slowly (about 3 seconds each).

I want to load `page 2` while the user is entering their search criteria into `Page 1`.  Once the user presses enter on `page 1`, I want `page 2` to display immediately.  While `page 2` is displaying (animating), I want to load `page 3`.  After `page 3` loads BUT not `before 5 seconds` I want `page 3` to load.

Excellent answers from everyone:  OK.  Here's what might work best:    Comments welcome!!!!

```
<script>
$(document).on('pageinit', '#first',  function(){

      $('#search').click(function(){ // When user submits form
          $.ajax({ // Call HTML for page 2 (adobe edge animation)
            url: "mypage2.html",
            success: function(html){ //When receiving data :
              $('#second').html(html); //puts data into second div
                $('#first').hide(); //hides the first one
                $('#second').show(); //shows the second one
                setTimeout(showThird,5000); //pretending there's a loading, only for demo purposes
            }
          })
      });

      $.ajax({ // Call HTML for page 3 (adobe edge animation)
        url: "mypage3.html",
        success: function(html){ //When receiving data :
          $('#third').html(html); //puts data into third div
            $('#third').hide(); //hides the third one
        }
      })

      function showThird(){ // hides second div, show third div.
          $('#second').hide();
          $('#third').show();
      }

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="first">
     <input type="button" id="search">
</div>
<div id="second">
</div>
<div id="third">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I could really use some help figuring out the best way to do this. I'm already using jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

Comment: which jquery mobile version are you using? you dont need all this _hectic_ code to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

HTML and the browsers that render it do not inherently behave like this.  You cannot queue pages into a loading buffer as you suggest.  HTML executes commands in a synchronous fashion, ie: when a page is called, the old page is discarded and the new one begins to load.  There is no way to change this fact...there are, however, some tricks to get the illusion of the effect you are looking for.

As mentioned in another answer, AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript & XML) is a technique utilized by almost every site/application today which allows you to pull content into a pre-existing page with an asynchronous call.  jQuery makes AJAX calls rather simple so I'll let you look up the code necessary.

You may want to consider loading the animated page (I am assuming it is a loading animation) when the form page is loaded.  Rather than making an additional call to pull the animation page, you can simply hide the animation initially...and show it when the form is submitted...then hide it again when the new information is pulled onto the page!

Answer (score 2):

You should load your pages using ajax.

For example, you would have one div containing page 1. When page 1 loads, page 2 is also loaded asynchronously and its content is loaded into another div, hidden.

When the user submits his search, div 1 is hidden, and div 2 is shown.

At the same time, page 3 is called asynchronously via ajax, loaded in a hidden div 3.

When loaded, div 2 is hidden, and div 3 is shown.

This is the ajax part :

```
$.ajax({ 
      url: "page2.html",
      success: function(html){ //When receiving data :
        $('#second').html(html); //puts data into second div
          $('#first').hide(); //hides the first one
          $('#second').show(); //shows the second one
      }
});
```

**Working demo JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/38DPJ/

Comment: Cool.  This is a big help.  Question for you....  You mention that page 2 content is loaded into another div, hidden.  I need some help understand that.  Where is that 'another div'.  Is it an empty div on Page 1 that has a style that is hidden?  Or, something else....   thanks!

Comment: @user1704787 Yes, that's exactly what it is, an empty div. Check my jsfiddle ! The second div is empty and originally hidden via the CSS, then shown via javascript when the page 2 content is loaded.

Comment: OK.  Sorry for being so 'thick', but would I need a second $.ajax script for loading the third page (url: "page3.html").  Would I also need to include "cache: true," so that the javascript files associated with Page2 and Page3 would also be preloaded?

Comment: @user1704787 No. Your page2 and page3 should only contain what's inside the body of those pages. The original page (page 1) should contain the head, and all the files the other parts are going to need.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks. I'll load all the scripts and such for pages 1, 2 and 3 in the head section of Page 1.  But where/how do insert the url for Page3 ?

Comment: @user1704787 I don't know how your search system works but I'm guessing you were calling a PHP page treating the request and returning a page. Do it with Ajax, the same way I did for page 2. And display the result in the third div.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use an `AJAX` call. Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "page2.html",
  cache: true,
  success: function(html){

  }
})
```

And for `page3` you can try

```
$.ajax({
      url: "page3.html",
      cache: true,
      success: function(html){

setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "page3.html";},5000);

      }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  This and other are really helpful.  Question for you.  I didn't know about the 'cache: true' option.  What does this do?  And, what is the default if this wasn't inserted?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1704787 by default is true and false for dataType, 'script' and 'jsonp'. In other words you dont have to include it here. If set to false it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.

Comment: So, since page 2 has some separate scripts (that what a lot of Adobe Edge is made up of), I'll HAVE to use the cache: true....  agreed?

Comment: @user1704787 yes it is better include it